# Output Array to CSV file is outputting the line length - powershell

Tags: powershell

I am working on a powershell script that outputs nmap scan data from a multitude of nmap .txt files to a CSV. Whenever I output the Data via Export-Csv C:\file.csv it is outputting the length of the lines, and not the actual data.

Any suggestions? Output Arrays seem to be something I am having issues grasping.

```
$fulloutput=@()

foreach ($File in GCI C:\*.txt){
$output=$null
$output+=$file.name + ","
    foreach ($result in (gc $file)){
        $output+=$result | ?{$_ -like "OS details*" -or $_ -like "Aggressive OS*"}
    }
    $fulloutput+=$output
}
$fulloutput | Export-Csv C:\nmap.csv
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is because you are passing string array to `export-csv` which is expecting object

if you want to force the behavior ,then you can try this example:

```
$c = @("dg","ert")                 
#you can replace the below variable with your $fulloutput                                                                               
$c| %{new-object psobject -property @{text=$_}} | Export-Csv test.csv  -NoTypeInformation                                              
notepad .\test.csv
```

Comment: Do I need replace the last line with this one?

Comment: I just got to work, and I was able to test this. Thank you for your help.